# TextFile ReWrite error in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I have two files - one contains a number of short strings (that I call Items) and the other contains the IDs for these short strings. I also have a number of other files, each of which contains a very long string that is broken up into thousands of smaller strings by means of line breaks. I need to find the number of times each short string ("Item") occurs in each of the large string files, as well as the starting and ending position for each hit.
My first task is to remove the line breaks in the large files so that the hits do not straddle across two or more smaller strings, and then find the number of occurrences and start and end positions of each short string in the large strings, and report these results using the ID numbers for each short string.
I am getting a `EInOutError (Access Denied)` error apparently at the `ReWrite(ResultFile)` line (in the bottom half of the second procedure in the code below). Not sure why. I can see the file created for the results of the first long string, but it is blank. Here is the code; pretty simple and straightforward, actually.  Thanks.

```
procedure TForm1.OpenStrCmdBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.execute then OpenStrEditBx.Text := OpenDialog1.FileName
else ShowMessage('Cannot open file!');
end;




procedure TForm1.FindItemfCmdBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, LenItem, NumTimes, offset: integer;
  Extension, FileName, Dir, Str, Item, ID: string;
  TempList,  IDList, ItemList: TStringList;
  searchResult: TSearchRec;
  ResultFile: TextFile;

begin
  IDList := TStringList.Create;
  ItemList := TStringList.Create;
  IDList.LoadFromFile('D:\...\IDs.txt');
  ItemList.LoadFromFile('D:\...\Items.txt');
  try
    Dir := ExtractFilePath(OpenStrEditBx.Text);

    //concatenate each line in each str sequence to get full string
    if FindFirst(Dir + '*.txt', faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
    repeat
      Extension := ExtractFileExt(OpenStrEditBx.Text);
      FileName := StringReplace(searchResult.Name, Extension, '', [rFReplaceAll, rFIgnoreCase]);//remove file extension to get only file name
      TempList := TStringList.Create;
      TempList.LoadFromFile(Dir + searchResult.Name);
      Str := '';
      for I := 1 to TempList.Count-1 do // I <> 0 to ignore ID in first line
      begin
        Str := Str + TempList[I];
        ProgressBar1.Position := (ProgressBar1.Position + 10) mod ProgressBar1.Max;
      end;
      TempList.Free;
      //Find number and location of occurrences of each Item
      for I := 0 to ItemList.Count-1 do
      begin
        Item := ItemList[I];
        LenItem := Length(Item);
        ID := IDList[I];
        NumTimes := 0;
        Offset := PosEx(Item, Str, 1);
        AssignFile(ResultFile, 'D:\...\' + FileName + '.txt');
        ReWrite(ResultFile);
        while Offset <> 0 do
        begin
          inc(NumTimes);
          if NumTimes > 0 then
             WriteLn(ResultFile, 'The ' + IntToStr(NumTimes) + 'th occurrence of ' + 'ID# ' + ID + ' is from Position# ' + IntToStr(Offset) + ' to Position# ' + IntToStr(Offset + LenItem- 1) + ' in ' + FileName);
          Offset := PosEx(Item, Str, Offset + LenItem);
        end;
        WriteLn(ResultFile, 'ID# ' + ID + ' occurs ' + IntToStr(NumTimes) + ' number of times in ' + FileName);
      end;
       CloseFile(ResultFile);
       ShowMessage(FileName + ' done!');

    until FindNext(searchResult) <> 0;
    FindClose(searchResult);

  finally
    IDList.Free;
    ItemList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What OS are you on that accepts `D:\...\` as a valid directory path? It's not on Windows. A single dot means *the current directory* and a double dot means *this directory's parent* .  There is no three dot relative path.

Comment: That was not the actual path.  It was fairly long, so I left out the middle portion of the path and replaced it with the three dots just for the purpose of posting it here.  In the actual code, I used the full path of course.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Oh, and I am using Windows 10

Comment: I'm not familiar with the old methods of assignfile, etc. Try it with a stringlist: create it, fill it, use .SavetoFile method, and free it. Maybe that will give a tip to what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it.

Comment: @juus, I just tried your suggestion - and it worked.  Thanks!  But I'm really curious to know what was wrong with the code I pasted above.  Hoping to hear from Delphi/Lazarus experts.  Thanks.

Comment: Take out all the complications and just using your assignfile, etc. try to pinpoint it. But. That method is very old school. When stringlists handle text files just fine (which is why they exist) why bother with obsolete code?